# Intellij not importing dependencies of modules

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

IntelliJ is not importing my modules dependencies for some reason. Like it's not taking into account my modules pom.xml. The dependencies added for example in the core module don't figure in the External library of the subject. As I'm not yet that familiar with intelliJ I assume the problem comes from the project structure so here it is:

[image: dependencies]

Comment: You might have to tell IntelliJ where the dependencies are located.  Press `SHIFT` + `CTRL` + `ALT` + `S`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to import the project as a "Maven Project".

- Remove the "wallbang" module with the "-" button.
- Click "+" -> "Import Module", then select the pom.xml.
- Configure it using the wizard.
- Click "Ok"

That should open up the Maven view and automatically include all dependencies.

Comment: Thanks, I'll mark this as answered although I took some different steps but that's my own fault. I'm putting it here for possible future readers. So on step 2 of this answer I accidently imported another version of the project with a similar name. Everything looked messed up so I deleted every module (step 1) deleted every .iml file and reimported the project.

Answer (score 0):

Importing from terminal and opening on another IDE might cause you troubles, so run the following code in your program and run it as you run the hello world app:

```py
import subprocess

module_name = "pandas"
subprocess.run(["pip", "install", module_name])
```